# Setup Node server with multiple websites and have each site on its own thread

Tags: node.js, multithreading, ubuntu-server

I have a laptop that I am running node on, a Ubuntu Server with a quad core processor.

There is a plan for 2-3 sites on this server and I am not a really good admin and needed help getting this one site going so I dont want to start from scratch and run a hypervisor. Is there a way to have node host 3 sites and have each of the run on their own thread of the processor? I understand Node is single threaded and while I really dont need to do this for performance (because its just for development) I do like this as an exercise in doing things in node and it would be cool! There is an entire second laptop for the database so Im not worried about resources.

So 3 sites on one instance of Ubuntu Server all on different threads.....

Comment: If you don't care about ports, then you can run three instances of node app having different ports.

Comment: So then how do I start node 3 times on the server? Because if I start node then I only get one application. Like "sudo nodejs app.js"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to accomplish.  Here are a couple scenarios:

1. Create three separate node.js servers, each listening to their own port and they will each be running their own node.js process independent of the other.  Then have each client connect to the appropriate port.
2. Create three separate node.js servers, each listening to their own port and they will each be running their own node.js process independent of the other.   Use NGINX as a proxy in front of the three web servers and you can let NGINX direct requests all on port 80 from each of the three domains to the appropriate node.js web server.  Using NGINX this way, all three web servers can appear to be be running on the default port 80 (or 443) and NGINX will separate them out and direct them to the appropriate web server process.
3. Create your own master node.js process that receives requests for all three domains, looks that the host header to see what domain the request was actually directed at and then forward that request to the appropriate child process.  This would be similar to the way clustering works in node.js, but each child process would be each of your different web servers.  Personally, I'd use the pre-built functionality in NGINX to do this for you (as described in option 2 above), but you could code it yourself if you didn't want to run NGINX.
4. Instead of NGINX, use some sort of load balancer that your ISP may already have to direct the incoming connections to the right server process.

Answer (score 0):

If you run 3 different applications ie. sites then they will be running as different processes on your server which assuming all run on different ports, there should be no problem running them simultaneously. When you refer to node being single threaded that applies to a single process so each process has its own event loop running.

Comment: So then how do I start node 3 times on the server? Because if I start node then I only get one application. Like "sudo nodejs app.js"